# PHP Select 10, 10 letter words from an array, limited by a pool of characters

Tags: php, arrays

this question may be more suited to code golf, but I thought I would try here first.

I have an array with 20,302 10 letter words in it: http://pastebin.com/NfzFiS92

I was wondering how I would be able to select 10 words from the array, limited by Scrabble characters. Which is...

9x A

2x B

2x C

4x D

12x E

2x F

3x G

2x H

9x I

1x J

1x K

4x L

2x M

6x N

8x O

2x P

1x Q

6x R

4x S

6x T

4x U

2x V

2x W

1x X

2x Y

1x Z

2x Blank

Comment: Yes, try codegolf. Here you need to show what you've done so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your scrabble letter frequencies like this:

```
$freqs = array(
"a"=>9,
"b"=>2,
"c"=>2,
...
);
```

Then you can build a function canBuild:

```
function canBuild($word){
    global $freqs;
    $temp = $freqs;
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($word);$i++){
        $letter = strtolower($word[$i]);
        if($temp[$letter]>0){
            $temp[$letter]--;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    $freqs = $temp;
    return true;
}
```

From here iterate over your words array however you like and collect the first 10 encounters which pass the canBuild test.